# Rails Associations Technique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a User model in which their are two booleans for admin and manager statuses, each manager can have only one **job** created, and each job can have many managers. I made a model for the jobs which have its attributes. I need a way to handle the relationship between the manager user and the job model. My problem here is that I don't need users with admin or without manager statuses to have a relationship with the job model, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
  attr_accessible :is_admin, :is_manager, job_id

  belongs_to :job
  validate :only_manager_belongs_to_job

  private

  def only_manager_belongs_to_job
    if !is_manager && job_id
      errors.add(:job_id, "Only a manager can have a job")
    end
  end
end

class Job
  has_many :managers, class_name: "User"
end
```

STI is overkill for this (and most other things it's used for).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why STI would be an overkill.

Comment: It's unnecessary complexity. In this situation, how would it help?

Comment: And I think this didn't handle that user has only one job.

Comment: I got an argument error on the validates line saying "You need to supply at least one validation"

Comment: Yeah, I thought I read your "And I think this didn't handle that user has only one job." in the other answer, but I guess you put it in both. My response: `job_id` is the only link between a manager and a job, and it can only be occupied by one value at a time. It is impossible for a manager to have more than one job.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)?. You will have to add type column and job_id column to users table

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Manager < User
  belongs_to :job
end

class Admin < User
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managers
end
```

Comment: Then how the manager model will include only the users with the manager boolean value true?

Comment: And I think this didn't handle that user has only one job.

Comment: @Wazery: From OP -  `I don't need users with admin or without manager statuses to have a relationship with the job model`. So in class `Manager`, `belongs_to :job` would mean that the manager has only one job

Comment: you would understand my solution more clearly if you read my link about STI

Comment: Yes manager should have only one job, and thanks for the useful link.